# SQL error 150 Foreign key

Tags: sql

I wanna add a foreign key to my table and it gives me an error, the reference has the same data type, any ideas?

Here's my code:

```
        CREATE TABLE order_task
      (
        order_number numeric (20) NOT NULL ,
        order_sending_date TIMESTAMP,
        order_profile_code varchar (20) NOT NULL ,
        order_weight decimal (20.10) NOT NULL ,
        order_piston_number numeric (1) NOT NULL
      );
      ALTER TABLE order_task ADD CONSTRAINT ord_num_dt_pk PRIMARY KEY (order_number , order_sending_date);

                 CREATE TABLE pre_product
         (
           pre_product_number numeric (5) NOT NULL ,
           pre_product_date TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
           pre_product_lenght_count numeric (5) NOT NULL ,
           pre_product_rod_count numeric (5) NOT NULL,
           pre_product_rod_lenght float (20) NOT NULL,
           pre_product_weight float (20) NOT NULL,
           pre_product_piston_number numeric (1) NOT NULL ,
           pre_product_profile_code varchar (20) NOT NULL ,
           pre_product_shift_number numeric (1) NOT NULL,
           pre_product_employee varchar (40) NOT NULL ,
           pre_product_scrap float (20) NOT NULL,
           pre_product_scrap_percentage float (3,3) NOT NULL ,
           pre_product_status varchar (40) NOT NULL,
           pre_product_order_number numeric (20) NOT NULL ,
           pre_product_order_date TIMESTAMP
         );
       ALTER TABLE pre_product ADD CONSTRAINT pp_num_date_pk PRIMARY KEY (pre_product_number,pre_product_date);

       ALTER TABLE pre_product ADD CONSTRAINT pp_on_pp_fk FOREIGN KEY (pre_product_order_number)
       REFERENCES order_task (order_number);

       ALTER TABLE pre_product ADD CONSTRAINT pp_on_ot_fk FOREIGN KEY (pre_product_order_date)
       REFERENCES order_task (order_sending_date);
```

the error appears in the last line when i try to add a foreign key between pre_product_order_date and order_sending_date

Comment: What is the **exact** error message? And which DBMS are you using? But `decimal (20.10)` should be `decimal (20,10)` in any DBMS that I know

Comment: For sql-server: `timestamp` should not be used to store dates. "The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type." See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=SQL.90).aspx. And also: "The Transact-SQL timestamp data type is different from the timestamp data type defined in the ISO standard." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.130).aspx. And finally: "The timestamp syntax is deprecated. This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server."

Comment: An FK must reference the whole PK, in this case both columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary key which you have created on the table is a composite primary key on two columns `order_number` and `order_sending_date`.
So, Foreign key should be created on both the columns together and not just part of it. As `pre_product` is the child table for `order_task` table.

```
ALTER TABLE pre_product
   ADD CONSTRAINT pp_on_pp_fk FOREIGN KEY (pre_product_order_number_date)
       REFERENCES order_task (order_number,order_sending_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

- `order_sending_date` as part of the PK? Seems like a bad design.
- `order_sending_date` is definitly not unique so if you want to define a FK you should define it on both columns

  ALTER TABLE pre_product ADD CONSTRAINT pp_on_pp__ot_fk FOREIGN KEY (pre_product_order_number,pre_product_order_date)
         REFERENCES order_task (order_number,order_sending_date);